# Size of neighborhood given by implicit function theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f_i:\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\to \mathbb{R}^n$ for $i\in \mathbb{N}$ be collection of smooth maps such that,

1. $f_i(0)=0$ for all $i$;
2. The Jacobian $Df_i$ is invertible at $0$ for all $i$;
3. There exists $M>0$ such that $|f_i|^2\leq M$ for all $i$ (i.e. $M$ is a uniform (independent of $i$) bound on the size of all $f_i$).

By (1) and (2), we can apply the implicit function theorem to all the $f_i$ at $0$: as a consequence, there exist neighborhoods $U_i\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ of $0\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and smooth maps $g_i:U_i\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $g_i(0)=0$ and $f_i(x,g_i(x))=0$ for all $x\in U_i$.

Let $B_{r_i}(0)\subset g_i(U_i)$ be the largest ball, centered at $0\in \mathbb{R}$, which is contained in the image $g_i(U_i)$. Note that the implicit function theorem ensures that $r_i>0$ for each $i$.

**Question 1:** Does there exist $R>0$ such that $r_i\geq R$ for all $i$? In other words, can the size of $g_i(U_i)$ go to zero as $i\to \infty$?

**Question 2:** More generally, what controls the size of the neighborhoods $U_i$ (or the size of the images $g_i(U_i)$) whose existence is given by the implicit function theorem?

Comment: Let $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be a bounded increasing function with $g(0)=0$ (e.g. $g(x)=\arctan(x)$).  A counterexample to Q.1 is $n=1$ and $f_i(x,y)=g(y-\frac{g(x)}{i})$.  I don't know about Q.2, but a lower bound on $\|D_xf_i\|$ might work.

Comment: Thanks for the counterexample. By $\|D_xf_i\|$ do you mean the operator norm? Or determinant? Why would such a lower bound help?

Comment: I was thinking operator norm, but you probably need more, like a bound on $D_yf_i(0)$ as well as an upper bound on $y''_i(x)$...  In the $n=1$ case, differentiating $f_i(x,y_i(x))=0$ gives $D_xf_i+D_yf_i y'_i(x)=0$, so $y'_i(x)=(D_yf_i)^{-1}D_xf_i$.  If $|D_xf_i(0)|>\epsilon$ and $|D_yf_i(0)|<\delta$, then $|y'_i(0)|>\epsilon/\delta$ uniformly in $i$.  The problem is if $y''_i(x)$ gets large as $i\to\infty$, then this isn't enough.